# I am trying to make an app with automator

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I am trying to make an app with automator that would take the user input which is a path to folder, then it would add it to mac os sidebar using mysides, everything works perfect but if the directory has spaces in it, it will break it and show as file instead of folder and do not work at all.

```bash
for f in "$@"
do
basename $f
s="$(basename -- $f)"
/usr/local/bin/mysides add $s file://$f
done
```

I tried using sed with `%20` but no luck to fix the issue.

```bash
for f in "$@"
do
basename $f
s="$(basename -- $f)"
/usr/local/bin/mysides add $s file://$(echo $f | sed 's/ /%20/g')
done
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You have to escape the path by wrapping in single or double quotes. Try `add '$s' 'file://$f'`

Comment: even with quotes still does not work /usr/local/bin/mysides add '$s' 'file://$f'

Comment: You have to use double quotes. Variable expansion/interpolation does not happen within single quotes.

Comment: even with double quotes same error ,can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found.

Comment: In general, wrap variable inside double-quotes unless the program doesn't work. It will happen less often than the program not working because of unwrapped variables.

Comment: so there isn't anyway to fix this ?

Comment: Does your script work when run standalone, i.e., outside of Automator? Sprinkle some echo statements to see what are the actual path variables. And please update the question with the latest version of your script.

Comment: i did try it stand alone outside automator still same issue

Comment: also if i use echo $f it totally show path with space

Answer (score 0):

I don't have **mysides** so I cannot test properly, but you need to surround shell variables with double quotes when you access them:

```
for f in "$@"
do
   basename "$f"
   s=$(basename -- "$f")
   /usr/local/bin/mysides add "$s" file://"$f"
done
```

Or, you can replace spaces with %20 like this:

```
.../mysides add "$s" "file://$(echo $f | sed 's/ /%20/g')"
```

Comment: can you please install mysides (brew install --cask mysides)

Comment: i tested urs same error i think its smth wrong with mysides

Comment: anyone dealt with mysides in spaces for folders?

Comment: if i make command in this way it work

Comment: /usr/local/bin/mysides add "$s" file:///Users/Testing/testing%20one/

Comment: question is how can i apply this to automatic make any space as %20

Comment: I have added a method, though I think you'dbe better off using `echo $f | jq -SrR @uri` since it will cope with things other than spaces.

Comment: work like a charm with "file://$(echo $f | sed 's/ /%20/g')" thank you so much but do u think i need to use echo $f | jq -SrR @uri or can i stick with echo $f | sed 's/ /%20/g')